# Adding ArrayList<String> inputs which are each referencing a double through enums

Tags: java, arraylist, enums, addition

In this program I was required to create an ArrayList called purse which would get US coin names inputted into it as strings. Then we are asked to assign each input value to its corresponding double value. So when the user types "penny" the program should recognize that the string "penny" refers to the double 0.01. Which I have done through enums in my Coin class. Now my task is to create a new method in my Purse class that adds the double values together. Which I have almost done, but I have put the code doing task inside the AddCoin method. Since I am required to create a new method for this task I was wondering if there is a way to  do it with what I have now.

```
package purse;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;




/**
 * The Purse program creates an ArrayList called purse that gets printed out,
  reversed, and transfered into another ArrayList called purse2. 
 *     
 *               - ArrayList purse 
 *               - ArrayList purse2
 *               - Scanner coin - the Scanner that is used to type the contents of ArrayList purse
 *               - Scanner coin2- the Scanner that is used to type the contents of ArrayList purse2
 *               - String input - contains Scanner coin and is used to fill ArrayList purse
 *               - String input2- contains Scanner coin2 and is used to fill ArrayList purse2
 *               - String end - sentinel for ending the process inputting strings into Scanner coin and Scanner coin2
 *      
 */
public class Purse  
{ 
  ArrayList<String> purse = new ArrayList<>(); 



   /**
    *  fills ArrayList purse and purse2 with U.S coin names 
    *  purse gets printed out and then again is printed in reverse
    *  purse2 is printed

    */






  public void addCoin()
  { 
      double sum = 0.0;
      String end = "done";

      Scanner coin = new Scanner (System.in); 
       String input = " ";

      System.out.println("Please put as many coins of U.S currency as you like into the purse, hit the ENTER button after each coin and, type 'done' when finished: ");

      while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase ("done"))

      {  
          input =  coin.nextLine();
          Coin c = new Coin(Coin.Value.valueOf(input));
            for(int i =0; i< c.getValue();i++)
                sum += c.getValue();
            System.out.println(sum);

       if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("penny")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("nickel")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("dime")||input.equalsIgnoreCase("quarter")||input.equalsIgnoreCase(end))
        {
            purse.add(input);
            purse.remove(end);

        }



       else{
           System.out.println("Please input a coin of U.S currency.");
           }
      }


  }

  /**
  @return ArrayList purse
  */
  public ArrayList<String> printPurseContents()
  { 
      System.out.println("Contents of the purse: " + purse);
      return purse;  
  }

  /** checks whether purse2 has the same coins in the same order as purse
     * @return 
     * @param purse2
   */



  public boolean sameContents(Purse purse2)
  {

      if (purse2.purse.equals(purse)) 
      {
          return true; 
      } 
      else
      {
          return false;
      }   

   }
  /**
   * checks whether purse2 has the same coins as in purse, disregarding the order
   * @param purse2
   * @return 
   */

  public boolean sameCoins(Purse purse2) 
  {

    if( purse2.purse.containsAll(purse))
    {
        return true; 
    }    
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
  } 


   /**
    * adds contents of purse into purse2 and clears purse of its contents
     * @param purse2    
    */
    public void transfer(Purse purse2)  
    {
               purse2.purse.addAll(purse);
                purse.clear();

     System.out.println("The second purse now has: " + purse2.purse );
     System.out.println("and the first purse has: " + purse);


    }



}
```

----------Coin Class

```
package purse;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/** private string name;
 * private double value;
 * sum up value method
 *
 * @author Thomas
 */
public class Coin 
{
  public static enum Value
  {
      penny(0.01), nickel(0.05), dime(0.10), quarter(0.25), done(0);

      double change;

      Value(double value)
      {
          this.change = value;
      }
  }
    private Value type;

    public Coin(Value type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public double getValue()
    {
        return type.change;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return type.name();
    }


   }
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `ArrayList<Coin>` instead of `ArrayList<String>` and then add a sum() method like:

```
public double sum() {
    double sum = 0d;
    for (Coin c : coins) {
        sum+=c.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to us an ArrayList<Coin> then my returns do not work and I cannot add my string inputs into my the array or use purse.remove(end). How could I fix that to go along with what you're saying?

Comment: Also, when I put this into my program I was told to initialize coins and the program set it as Iterator<Coin> coins. Then it complained that it wasn't initialized so it set it to null. Which doesn't really work. Is there anything else to set that to?